# Is the below sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

"I ***will*** happen upon the...." *Happen upon* is completely circumstancial according to most dictionaries. So, is it grammatical to use "will" in the above sentence?

Comment: *Logically*, it's not that easy to come up with an utterance where the sequence *I will **happen upon** [some unforeseen chance encounter]*, because *I **will** [blah blah]* implies something *intended / foreseeable*. But syntactically speaking there's no problem, and it's perfectly logical in contexts like *I'm going for a walk in the forest. If I'm lucky, **I will happen upon** a nice puffball mushroom that I can cook for my tea later*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - or habitual/periodic - from time to time on my walks in the park I will happen upon someone with a dog.

Comment: Are you asking if it's grammatical or if it makes sense? These are two different concepts.

Comment: [correction: grammatical]

Comment: Thanks for your comments! And yes, I was asking if it's grammatically correct, and not if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Grammar doesn't care about whether your sentence makes sense.

A famous example sentence to demonstrate this is, "*Colorless green ideas sleep furiously*". This sentence has perfect grammar, but no meaning.

So yes, your phrase is grammatical.

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately, most people would choose to read what makes sense to them and not bother about it being grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where the phrase makes reasonable sense.

> Sometimes when I am hiking in the woods I come across interesting things. You may think they are rare. But when you get into the back country they become predictable. I **will happen upon** a mushroom fairy circle about one hike in three.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? I scoured the internet but couldn't find any.

Comment: I am quoting that emminent source of goodness and light, my self.

Comment: "Emminent" and "my self"? Gosh, I remember why I don't spend much time in ELL.

Comment: @NoamanAli  You claim not to spend much time in ELL? Citation needed!